# tabout in Stata

Tags: stata, interpretation

I am trying to use the `tabout` command in Stata to produce a table showing summary statistics of the age variable.  What I want is something similar to `summarize age, detail` output but to produce output similar to MS Word format.

> tabout age using table111.txt, c(skewness age kurtosis age mean age
>    median age sd age)    f(0c) sum h3(nil) npos(both)

does not produce the results I want.

Any suggestions on how the code should be adjusted? Also what if I want to include a second variable in the table and the summary statistics of same?

Comment: What do you want your results to look like and how does what `tabout` produces deviate from that? Without that information we have to guess at what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wonder why I had points deducted for this question when it was legitimate and answered appropriately

Comment: A late response, but whoever downvoted this (I don't know who it was) presumably thought more or less as @Maarten Buis commented. It remains true that "does not reproduce the results I want" is a poor problem report.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like that with the `estout` package. There you would type:

```
estpost summarize age, detail
esttab . using table111, cells("skewness kurtosis mean p50 sd") noobs rtf
```

You can read more here:
http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_estpost.html#summarize

If you want to include a second variable, say `hours`, to that table, you just type:

```
estpost summarize age hours, detail
esttab . using table111, cells("skewness kurtosis mean p50 sd") noobs rtf
```

Answer (score 1):

The `publish` command is a very useful package if your ultimate goal is to format this in word. It will look prettier than text:

```
publish open example.doc ,doc
publish table age, c(mean age... )
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try the following command into Excel:

```
local savedirectory "C:\yourdirectory\yourfile"

logout, save(`savedirectory') excel replace : summarize age
```

Comment: You should document where `logout` comes from.